# bash: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/go: Bad address

Tags: go, homebrew, linuxbrew

I did an brew upgrade and afterwards keep getting an bad address error.
Tried to uninstall/reinstall everything, but cant figure out what is the problem.

`bash: /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/go: Bad address`

Im new to terminal and linux, so all advice is welcome.

I tried brew doctor. It says "No developer tools installed." and after i 'brew install gcc'  it says gcc is already installed and up-to-date.

Comment: Please consider not using this contraption on Linux. Please do `apt install golang-go` and be done with it. Once you're comfortable with Go, you'll be able to use already installed Go to build yourself a newer version of Go, if badly needed.

Comment: If, for some reason, you're not comfortable with the version of Go packaged in your OS, consider [downloading an official `.tar.gz` package](https://go.dev/dl/) and unwrapping it. Still, if you're about just starting with the language, I'd recommend to start small and install what's packaged in your OS. Bleeding-edge versions of the language are usually required by those who uses the language on their $dayjob, and, once, in such situation, you usually build Go from the sourc ecode, not mess with non-Linux solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Use the official Go installation:

[Go: Download and install](https://go.dev/doc/install)

For full support, avoid OS package managers, Homebrew, and so forth.

---

First, remove any previous installations by other methods, for example, Homebrew.

Comment: Without defining what "full support" means, your answer is dubious.

Comment: Feeling something is obvious might be merely a manifestation of the lack of knowledge. Or may be not.

Comment: there is a reason for the existence of package managers.

Answer (score 1):

Little late, but this post was a suggestion for me when I ran into a similar issue with Go and Brew.

When Brew updates the version of Go (1.19.3 -> 1.19.5 in my case) that it is providing, for some reason it does not correctly update the `GOROOT` environment varaible. Correcting the value of the variable fixed the issue for me.

```bash
export GOROOT=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/go/<go_version>/libexec

# example
export GOROOT=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/go/1.19.5/libexec
```